# laravel Binding a property of the Model to selected values with getTagsAttribute()

Tags: laravel

i have problems with the model binding and the selected authors in the edit form and I used ->all() and it's still not working i have laravel 5.1.26
i tried and nothing happen and i tried 
    return $this->authors()->lists('id')->toArray();

**my model Book.php**

```
class Book extends Model
{
    public function section()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Section','id');
    }

    /**
     * many to many relation between author and books
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Author','books_authors_relationship','book_id','author_id')->withTimestamps();
    }


    public function getAuthorListAttribute()
    {
         return $this->authors->lists('id')->all();
    }

}
```

**and my controller**

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $authors = Author::lists('first_name','id')->all();
        $book = Book::find($id);
        return view('books.edit_book',compact('book','authors'));
    }
```

**and my edit_book.blade**

```
<div class="form-group ">
    {!! Form::label('author_list', 'Enter Another Author:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('author_list[]', $authors, null,['class'=>'form-control','multiple']) !!}
    </div>
```

Comment: have you set up the relation between book and authors?

Comment: yes every thing is ok and i can insert a new but when edit the selected authors not display it display all authors

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit? What are the results you're getting and what are the results you want to get? I don't see you use the getAuthorListAttribute anywhere...

Comment: i want selected authors in multiple select box in edit page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group ">
    {!! Form::label('author_list', 'Enter Another Author:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('author_list[]', $authors, $book->author->lists('id')->all(),['id' => 'authors','class'=>'form-control','multiple']) !!}
    </div>
```

thanks every one